# How to select an already-made partition to install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I have Windows 8 on my PC right now and I would like to install Ubuntu. On my HDD I have following partitions (I see the names form a partition software I use which is called "MiniTool Partition Wizard"):

> ```
> 1) *:SYSTEM (FAT32)
> 2) *: (Other)
> 3) C:OS (NTFS)
> 4) D: (NTFS)
> 5) G: (NTFS)  <- this is the one I created for Ubuntu
> 6) *:Recovery
> ```

All I want to do is to Install Ubuntu on `G:` partition.

The problem comes when I am in the Ubuntu installation page abd I select the option to manually partition the Hard Drive.

Names shown in that window are not the same as the ones shown on windows, and I cant recognize and install.

And I obviously want to have a dual-boot with Ubuntu and W8.

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Before you go for an Ubuntu - Win8 dual boot I recommend you should do a bit of research.. please check these [AU Qs on Win8 issues](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=i%20tried%20to%20dual%20boot%20ubuntu%20on%20windows%208%20and%20now%20nothing%20is%20working)

Answer (score 1):

As i can't comment yet, i'll post this as an answer.
Again someone correct me if i am wrong with my answer.

The G: partition you have is formatted as NTFS.
If you want to install Ubuntu it is best not to format the partition.
The problem however will be that you will be unable to access the partition from Windows.

On a side note, is the G: partition you made a seperate disc or another partition of a single disc?
Part of Ubuntu prefers to be installed at the beginning of a disc. (could be wrong here)

Comment: Since when does Ubuntu not use NTFS?  Have they discontinues that feature?  I'm still on 12.04, so maybe recent versions have changed.

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes NTFS does not support the file rights and security in the same way as Ubuntu does.

Comment: That's true.  But that's a lot different than saying it doesn't use it.  And if you don't need to access the Linux partition from Windows, then using Ext4 or similar would be much better.  Perhaps you should edit your post

Comment: I've never had any problems with using any part of a disk for Linux.  I don't see why it should care, unless the BIOS doesn't support the full size of the disk.

Comment: Isn't it so that /boot needs to be at the beginning of a disc or at least before a certain sector?

Comment: I've never heard that, and never had a problem.  Now, some people might put data that is accessed often on a part of the disk that can be accessed quicker, but it's not something that's required.

Answer (score 1):

Linux has no concept of separate drives; everything is one file system, and other drives (partitions, actually) are mounted somewhere on the single filesystem.  Everything can be accessed from the root directory.

So the best way to handle your situation is to either delete that partition and let Ubuntu create one, or note the sizes of the partitions to make sure you get the right one - assuming they are not close to the same size.

Most likely, your Windows partitions will be sda1, sda2, etc; this means the first drive, first partitions, and the sd is one of the labels for disk drives.  But the one for Ubuntu is probably the highest number, such as sda3, sda4 or sda5.  Still, it's best to confirm by checking the size.  Or, if you are installing from a live CD, you can run gparted to visually see the partitions, and also see how much data each partition has.

Answer (score 1):

To use an existing partition for your Ubuntu installation you must choose "something else", then click "change" for the partition you wish to use. While not required it is recommend to have a swap partition so you might want to trim a little off that NTFS one for swap before starting the installation process.

Screenshot of selecting a partition for Ubuntu to install on (make sure to check the "format the partition" box, even though this photo shows it unchecked):

https://www.copy.com/s/JQbwzdx6ishL/screen_shot_iuoedww7oid_18.PNG

www.copy.com/s/Hk0uRTzAB4Yo/screen_shot_iuoedww7oid_19.PNG

www.copy.com/s/NdCBTXh7UM2T/screen_shot_iuoedww7oid_20.PNG

I strongly recommend you backup your UEFI partition before installing Ubuntu. You can do this by creating an archive (.zip .tar etc) or even just copying and pasting the files that are currently stored on your FAT32 system partition.

Sources:

[Need advice installing Ubuntu on 2nd storage drive for windows 7 computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430036/need-advice-installing-ubuntu-on-2nd-storage-drive-for-windows-7-computer)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's different.It will be like `dev/sda1` or `dev/sda2` etc.It's not just like C,D,F partitions in windows.Indentify the correct partition by used and unused spaces.

My opinion is Go back into Windows and find the used, unused space on your G partition.Note it down on paper.It will helps you to easily identify your G partition during Ubuntu installation.Otherwise you gonna mess with partitions.

Atlast format your G partion to ext4 filesystem during Ubuntu installation.So that only, you can be able to install Ubuntu on that partition.

Comment: I think he might regret it if he formats to ext4, because he won't be able to get to it at all from windows.  I didn't see anything about multiple users on his Windows installation, and if someone gets access to his computer, they can get into the Linux system fairly easily anyway.

Comment: he can't able to format a partition to ext4 filesystem on Windows.I can't catch your point about multiple users.

Comment: Actually, now I don't see your point about "only you will be able to install Ubuntu on that partition", or your point about formatting in Windows, but none of that matters because my point is that he might regret not being able to see the partition at all from Windows if it is ext4.  That is, I'm saying not to rormat it in ext4; it doesn't matter whether he doesn't (can't) do it in windows or in Ubuntu, does it?

Comment: Already `G: (NTFS)` G partition is in NTFS format.So he can be able to view that on Windows.